# bad request while using multipart in nestjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I want to upload file and use dto to validate other things in nest
but when send request by post man I get bad request (that's from dto ) and when I remove send file everything works fine

This is my controller :

```
@Post()
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('image', SaveImageToStorage))
  // @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File ,
  create(
    @Body() createTicketDto: CreateTicketDto,
    @Request() req,
  ) {
    try {
      // console.log(image);
      console.log(createTicketDto);
      // return this.ticketService.create(createTicketDto)  ;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}
```

and this is the error after sending my request from postman :

```
{
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "statusCode": 400
}
```

[image: postmanimage]

I cant upload image and get all files !

I need an answer why this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, check your imports, maybe problem in them.

`FileInterceptor` import from "@nestjs/platform-express", `UseInterceptors` from "@nestjs/common".

Remove file from your dto, if it exist. File you are going to get using this way: `@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File`. Use DTO for other things.

Your `SaveImageToStorage` gotta look like this:

```
{
storage: diskStorage({
  destination: './uploads',
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const name = file.originalname.split('.')[0];
    const fileExtenstion = file.originalname.split('.')[1];
    const newFileName = name.split(" ").join('_')+'_'+Date.now()+'.'+fileExtenstion;

    cb(null, newFileName);
  }
 }),
}
```

`import {diskStorage} from "multer";` 
 and 
`import {extname} from "path";`

Comment: Thanks for your help . i checked my ` saveImageToStorage` and as i usually do in express i had been adding 2 new params to req.body so when i uploaded image they send me error back ! i removed them and now everything is fine